# High Mysql Connexions in Sleeping state + High number of PHP instances running / Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, nginx, process

**UPDATE
Still in pain ... nothing found :(
I'm honestly willing to donate to anyone who could jelp me solve this, it's getting obsessional lol.**

On a Proxmox distrib, I have a VM with a Debian installed.
ON this Debian : Nginx / PHP5-FPM / APC / Memcached and MySQL are running with a big MAGENTO multi-website setup.

Sometimes, (randomly or around 9am depends) The server load is increasing.
What I can see during this peek is :

- High number of PHP-FPM instances in HTOP
- Higyh number of MySQL connexions with most of them in sleeping state with a big "moment" value like 180 or sometimes more.
- Server's memory is not full, free -h tells me memory is not the issue here.
- TCP connexions from visitors is not high so, I don't think trafic is the issue neither

Looks like there is something (a php script I would say), that is triggered either by the cron or by a visitor (like a research or something else), and it's taking a lot of time to process, probably locking some MySQL tables and preventing other processes to run, leading to a massive freeze.

I'm trying hard to figure out what is causing this problem, or just find "ways" to debug it eficiently.

#### What I tried already :

- Tracing some of the php processes with HTOP to find 
  some informations. That's how I found out that mysql's process had some message idnicating it cannot connect to a ressource because it was busy.
- Searched in /var/log/messages and /var/log/syslog for information but got nothing relevant.
- Searched in /var/log/mysql for some error logs but got nothing at all.
- Searched in /var/log/php5-fpm.log and got many messages indicating that processes are exiting with code 3 after a "LONG" period of time (probably the process trying to get mysql ressource and never getting it ?) like :

`WARNING: [pool www] child 23839 exited with code 3 after 1123.453563 seconds from start`
or even :
`WARNING: [pool www] child 29452 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 2471.593537 seconds from start`

- Searched in Nginx website's error file and found multiple messages indicating that visitors connexions timed out due to the 60 seconds timeout I set in Nginx config file.

#### Here are my settings :

*Nginx website's config file :*

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite / /index.php last;
    }

    try_files $uri =404;
    expires off;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 60s;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.*\.php)(/.*)?$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

*Nginx main config file :*

```
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 60;
    client_max_body_size 30M;
```

**PHP-FPM is in onDemand mode**

`default_socket_timeout = 60`
`mysql.connect_timeout = 60`

*PHP-FPM pool's config file*

```
    pm=ondemand
    pm.max_children = 500
    pm.start_servers = 10
    pm.min_spare_servers = 5
    pm.max_spare_servers = 10
    pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s;
    pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s;
    pm.max_requests = 5000 (was thinking about reducing this value to force processes to respawn, if someone has experience with it, I'm interested in hearing it)
```

Thank you for your time reading this, I will update the content here if needed.

Regards
Sorcy

Comment: IIm trying to find a way to figure out what is causing this issue. Is there a way to identify which PHP Process Ids are linked to the sleeping mysql Ids, and then find what is the file that is being read by php ?

Comment: God this bug is annoying, still searching ...

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the cronjobs in crontab and Magento to make sure this is not any job?

Does this weird server behaviour slowdown your site? Im not sure, but this can also be an Slowloris DDos attack, where a lot HTTP connections open and because of a bug doesnt get closed. Maybe I gave you a hint with that.

Comment: my `crontab -e` does contain a line to run the cron.sh inside mangento's folder.
In Magento's back-office, I do have a list of task run by cron, like clearing captchas, doing other things .. but everything look smooth.

Comment: And of course yes, it does slowdown the website a lot, because every PHP process is using 3-4% of CPU and the whole load is increasing. :(